# Laravel: Can't find access_token and refresh_token on request

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.5

When I'm logging in, it seems my data response different I'm confused cause I'm looking for access_token and refresh_token but the only available here X-CSRF-TOKEN and X-XSRF-TOKEN then there's no more other token

BTW, I'm using vue js and I want to store my access_token to localStorage. And also I'm using default laravel authentication for the login

```
export default{
    $validates: true,
    data(){
        return{
            login:{
                username : '',
                password : '',
                remember : ''
            },
            disabled: 0,
            indeterminate : false,
            showLoader: false
        }
    },
    methods:{
        submit(){
            this.showLoader = true;
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                if(result){

                    console.log(this.login.username);
                    /*axios.post('/prod/login', this.login)
                    .then(response => console.log(response));*/

                    axios({
                        method:'post',
                        url : '/prod/login',
                        data: {
                            email : this.login.username,
                            password : this.login.password,
                            remember : this.login.remember
                        },
                        responseType: 'JSON'
                    })
                    .then(response=>{
                        if(response.status == 200){
                            console.log(response);  
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                if (error.response) {
                  console.log(error.response);
                }
              });


                    console.log('submited');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('mali e');

            });
        }
    },
    mounted(){
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess u need middleware when it comes to access.

Comment: An abstract of your Laravel api-side would be helpful as this is a multifaceted problem and I can't see much wrong with your js at a glance.

Comment: I understand I just integrate passport of laravel thanks for the info